# return observable from angular service

Tags: angular, service, angular2-observables, angular-httpclient

I'm using an angular service to get data via Httpclient and fill an array and return the array to the component. I think I should use observable but I can't figure how to do it.
here is my code so far"
my component.ts"

```
import { ZoomService } from './../services/zoom.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
providers: []
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
constructor(private zoom: ZoomService) {
}
spots: string[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
this.zoom.dosomthing();
//here I try to access the spot array in the service. but it is empty!
this.spots = this.zoom.spots;
//if I log the spots here it is an empty array!
console.log(this.spots);
}
}
```

and here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ZoomService {
spots: string[] = [];
constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { 
}

dosomthing() {
this.httpService.get('./assets/plates/plate1/spot.json').subscribe(data 
=> {
this.spots = data as string[];
const spots = this.spots;
//here the spot array is not empty!
console.log(this.spots); 
});
}
}
```

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data - Angular docs are very detailed. So `getConfig()` method from `/config.service.ts` returns `Observable`. Now in  `config.component.ts` in `showConfig` method you subscribe to it and bind the response to component property. In your case the `data` will be spots you return from the service.

Comment: @AliHaghighi where is your return type how to get any data from function `dosomthing`? and why use `subscribe` in service?

Comment: my code works perfectly if I don't use a service and instead of this.zoom.dosomthing(); I use this code this.httpService.get('./assets/plates/plate1/spot.json').subscribe(data 
=> {
this.spots = data as string[];
const spots = this.spots;     but I want use a service so my code be usable in other components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, that's how you should do it.

```
//component
import { ZoomService } from './../services/zoom.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
    spots: string[] = [];

    constructor(private zoom: ZoomService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.zoom.dosomthing()
            .subscribe((res: string[]) => {
                this.spots = res;
                console.log(this.spots);
            });
    }
}

//service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ZoomService {
    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {}

    dosomthing(): Observable<string[]> {
        return this.httpService.get<string[]>('./assets/plates/plate1/spot.json');
    }
}
```